# Edit orm object based on query with label fields

Tags: sqlalchemy

Time for more pushing the limits of sqlalchemy. It never ceases to amaze!

### Background

I have table for devices, and a table to record physical links between them.

```
class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ =  "device"
    device_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False)


class PhysicalLink(Base):
    __tablename__ =  "physical_link"
    physical_links_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)

    device_id_1 = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(Device.device_id), nullable=False)
    device_port_1 = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False)

    device_id_2 = sa.Column(sa.types.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(Device.device_id), nullable=False)
    device_port_2 = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False)

    cable_number = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False)
```

When I dealing with the physical links for a know device, I don't want to have to always have if statements to decide whether I should be looking at device_[id|port]_ 1 or 2, so I did:

```
physical_links_table = PhysicalLinks.__table__
physical_links_ua = union_all(
    select((
        physical_links_table.c.physical_links_id,
        label('this_device_id', physical_links_table.c.device_id_1),
        label('this_device_port', physical_links_table.c.device_port_1),
        label('other_device_id', physical_links_table.c.device_id_2),
        label('other_device_port', physical_links_table.c.device_port_2),
        physical_links_table.c.cable_number,
        ),),
    select((
        physical_links_table.c.physical_links_id,
        label('this_device_id', physical_links_table.c.device_id_2),
        label('this_device_port', physical_links_table.c.device_port_2),
        label('other_device_id', physical_links_table.c.device_id_1),
        label('other_device_port', physical_links_table.c.device_port_1),
        physical_links_table.c.cable_number,
        ),),
    ).alias('physical_links_ua')

class PhysicalLinksDir(object):
    pass


physical_links_dir_mapper = orm.mapper(PhysicalLinksDir, physical_links_ua)
physical_links_dir_mapper.add_property(
    'this_device', orm.relation(Device, primaryjoin=(PhysicalLinksDir.this_device_id == Device.device_id)))
physical_links_dir_mapper.add_property(
    'other_device', orm.relation(Device, primaryjoin=(PhysicalLinksDir.other_device_id == Device.device_id)))
```

This allows me to do:

```
physical_links = (db_session
    .query(PhysicalLinksDir)
    .filter(PhysicalLinksDir.this_device_id = my_device.device_id)
    .options(joinedload('other_device')))
for pl in physical_links:
    print pl.other_device
```

(Did I remember to tell you that I think that sqlalchmey rocks!)

### Question

What do I need to do to make it possible to modify PhysicalLinksDir instance attributes, and be able to commit them back to the db?

Comment: Which of the attributes would you like to be able to modify? Would you like to be able to also add/delete links using this ´PhysicalLinksDir´?

Comment: I want to basically edit all attrs - [this_device_port, other_device_id, other_device_port, cable_number]

I would like to add and delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you will have to be very careful with updating it the way you want, 
because those view objects `PhysicalLinksDir` will not always be in-sync with the
underlying `Device` and `PhysicalLink` you might have in session/database. 
I obviously do not know your requirements, but I prefer not to have such inconsistencies when working with my model.

Also, there is a problem with the kind of mapping you have. You would expect to have 2 rows of `PhysicalLinksDir` for each row of `PhysicalLink` (one for each side), but if you try it, you will see this is not the case. The reason for this is that the first column (`physical_links_id`) is considered to be a `primary_key` so the 
query object will discard the second one with the same value.
In order to fix it, you need to configure the `primary_key` manually. Assuming there can be only one
connection between two different Devices, the solution below will do the trick. You might need to extend it to include the `port` as well:

```
physical_links_dir_mapper = orm.mapper(PhysicalLinksDir, physical_links_ua,
    # @note: add this
    primary_key=[physical_links_ua.c.physical_links_id, physical_links_ua.c.this_device_id],
    )
```

**DELETE**: Now, to support `delete`, all you need to do is to add a relationship between your `PLD` and the actual `PhysicalLink` and the `session.delete(my_PLD); session.commit()` will also delete the `PhysicalLink` it represents:

```
physical_links_dir_mapper.add_property(
    'physical_link', orm.relation(PhysicalLink, primaryjoin=(
                              PhysicalLinksDir.physical_links_id == PhysicalLink.physical_links_id),
                              foreign_keys=[PhysicalLinksDir.physical_links_id]
    ))
```

But in fact, the deletion might work out of the box as the model is soft-linked to the `physical_link` table.

**INSERT**: Well, this is easily done with the `PhysicalLink` object directly, so I would just keep it this way.

**UPDATE**: You could potentially probably achieve this with [Session Events](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html?highlight=hooks#session-events), but the most simple way would be just to wrap all the attributes in a `@property` which would delegate the change to the proper object.

**IMPORTANT**: I still think that this way of working is not really nice, because the links are not updated automatically and your in-memory `UnitOfWork` might be inconsistent.

---

*If also would be useful to understand why you think this way of working with your objects would be better? What are the use cases of this app?*