# How to query the attribute(s) from an Association table (SQLalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a self-Referential Association Relationship and I'm trying to figure out how to get the associated attribute(s) from the association table.

[image]

This is the code from the model (based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958963/self-referential-association-relationship-sqlalchemy)):

```
class Contact(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'contact'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.Unicode(120), nullable=False, unique=False)
to_contacts = association_proxy('to_relations', 'to_contact')
from_contacts = association_proxy('from_relations', 'from_contact')

def __repr__(self):
    return "User(%r)" % self.name

class ContactRelation(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'contactrelation'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
from_contact_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact.id'))
to_contact_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact.id'))
relation_type = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)

from_contact = db.relationship(Contact,
                               primaryjoin=(from_contact_id == Contact.id),
                               backref='to_relations')
to_contact = db.relationship(Contact,
                             primaryjoin=(to_contact_id == Contact.id),
                             backref='from_relations')
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**
I want to query a contact and get the contacts related to him. That part works. But I also want to get the relation_type between them.

My assumption was that the Contact object returned would contain the relation_type but it doesn't.

How can I query such attributes for a Contact object from the association table?

Comment: That information is in the association object `ContactRelation`. How would you decide what `Contact.relation_type` would even be? After all given this model a `Contact` can be related to many others.

Comment: @IljaEverilä So how should the model look like to achieve that in the relationship?

Comment: Your model already looks fine. If you need the relation type along with the `Contact`, iterate over `Contact.to_relations` / `Contact.from_relations` and you get both `ContactRelation.relation_type` and `ContactRelation.from_contact` / `ContactRelation.to_contact`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That worked, thanks!