# How to build a self-referential associative data structure?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a hierarchical structure consisting of Nodes where each Node is linked both to several "up" nodes as well as "down" nodes. However, when I run the code below, I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
between parent/child tables on relationship Node.links_up - there are
multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument,
providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key
reference to the parent table.
```

"Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument" ... but that's what I'm doing in the definition of Link, why isn't it honored? I can't do it in Node, because Node doesn't have any foreign keys.

This is already the watered-down version, I tried and completely failed to build something with "secondary joins" so that I could have relationships Node.nodes_up and Node.nodes_down, but that seems even more hopeless. Any hints on how to pull this off?

The documentation has examples of using association objects as well as adjacency relationships, but not both together.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name          = Column(String(100))

    links_up = relationship('Link', back_populates='node_down')
    links_down = relationship('Link', back_populates='node_up')

class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    up_id         = Column(ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)
    down_id       = Column(ForeignKey('node.id'), primary_key=True)

    node_up = relationship('Node',
                           foreign_keys=[up_id],
                           back_populates='links_down')

    node_down = relationship('Node',
                             foreign_keys=[down_id],
                             back_populates='links_up')

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

db = Session()
r = Node(name='Parent')
db.add(r)
db.commit()
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958963/self-referential-association-relationship-sqlalchemy) but it uses backref() which I (and sqlalchemy as of late) don't like. It should be possible with back_populates as well.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/self_referential.html

Comment: Of course I read that, like I mentioned in my original post. But that only covers a one-to-many self referential list, where one parent can have many children, but each child has only one parent. In my case, each cild can also have many parents.