# Bidirectional Friendship Relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to implement a bidirectional friendship relationship using SQLAlchemy.

```
User A <------> User B <------> User C      User D
```

Can someone give me an example / code snippet of this?

Comment: Please look at the code of the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/25177451/99594 and ignore the question itself. The code there is an example of *self-referential many-to-many relationship*.

Answer (score 1):

You need a many to many JOIN table, because each individual can have many friends.  The table will have a composite primary key consisting of two foreign keys that refer back to the individual table.

Comment: Thanks duffymo, I understand your point. However, I am not sure how to do it the SQLAlchemy ORM way..

Comment: ORM means "object relational mapping", so I'm guessing that your Friend class will have a Collection of Friend instances.  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html